# How can I prevent an <hr> tag from disappearing when printing a page?

Tags: html, css

In an html template that I have for a Flask website I'm building, I just want to throw out information on the page so I can hit "Ctrl + P" and print the page from there. I want a line separating the different sections, so I've been using an `<hr>` tag to break it up visually. This works fine when I load into the page, however it disappears once I try to go print it using "Ctrl + P." A example of my `<hr>` tag is below and two images to show it...

`<hr style="height:2px;width:100%;text-align:center;margin-left:0">`

[Line visible in page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G4s4n.png)

[Line missing in print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fn0kC.png)

I've been messing around a bit with the `@media print` tag in my css and have tried setting `display: block;` to my `<hr>` tags, but to no avail.

Is there anyway around this? Thank you!

Comment: The most likely explanation is that you browser printing is set not to print backgrounds. Have you checked this?